# Getting list of my manager's directs except few of them using my employee id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an employee table with EmployeeId, ReportsToEmployeeId column, which gives list of employees in an org and whom the employee reports to.

```
EmployeeId, ReportsToEmployeeId
EMP2        EMP1
EMP3        EMP1
EMP4        EMP1
EMP5        EMP1
EMP6        EMP1
EMP7        EMP1
```

I also have one more table - **AssistantManager**. This table specified under a manager, few of the directs act as assistant manager (team lead). This table contains two column, AssistantManagerEmployeeId, ReportsToEmployeeId.

```
AssistantManagerEmployeeId, ReportsToEmployeeId
EMP3                        EMP1
EMP6                        EMP1
```

Consider I am one of the Assistant Manager (EMP3) of a Manager (EMP1). I need to query list of my manager's (EMP1) directs except AssistantManagers (EMP3, EMP6). So the result should contains -

```
EmployeeId, ReportsToEmployeeId
EMP2        EMP1
EMP4        EMP1
EMP5        EMP1
EMP7        EMP1
```

I am writing the query as below

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
JOIN AssistantManager ON AssistantManager.ReportsToEmployeeId = Employee.ReportsToEmployeeId
WHERE AssistantManager.AssistantManagerEmployeeId = @MyEmployeeId
AND Employee.EmployeeId NOT IN 
(
-- Gives list of Assistant Managers who as under my manager
SELECT OtherRec.AssistantManagerEmployeeId
FROM AssistantManager myRec
JOIN AssistantManager OtherRec ON OtherRec.ReportsToEmployeeId = myRec.ReportsToEmployeeId
Where myRec.AssistantManagerEmployeeId = @MyEmployeeId
)
```

Please let me know a query that more efficient. I am actually looking if possible to write without a sub query.

Many Thanks, Thirumalai M

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data as DDL + DML, and desired result. As it is now, it's impossible to answer.

Comment: Usually using a join is perfectly fine, what is your problem/why don't you like to use it?

Comment: Hi. I edited the question with example and also rewtritten little more context what I plan to do.

Comment: @Thirumalai Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should be like below for better efficiency

```
SELECT 
  E.*--- everything from Employee table
FROM Employee E 
  JOIN 
  AssistantManager AM
        ON  E.ReportsToEmployeeId =AM.ReportsToEmployeeId  AND AM.AssistantManagerEmployeeId=@MyEmployeeId -- check to include your manager's directs
  WHERE NOT EXISTS -- check to exclude all AMs under your manager
    (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM AssistantManager AM2 
        WHERE 
            AM2.ReportsToEmployeeId=AM.ReportsToEmployeeId AND 
            E.EmployeeID= AM2.AssistantManagerEmployeeId
    )
```

Sample output:
[image]

Comment: Hi DhruvJoshi. Thanks for the reply. This query resulting all the directs including Assistant managers except my record. Here the query checking AM.AssistantManagerEmployeeId=@MyEmployeeId and E.EmployeeId <>AM.AssistantManagerEmployeeId. So it is excluding only my record, not other assistant managers. I am getting EMP2, EMP4, EMP5, EMP6 and EMP7 as result (where EMP6 should not present in the result).

Comment: @Thirumalai Please see updated answer. Please accept my reply as correct answer if it worked for you- so that other users can benefit: from knowing that the answer works and by having the question marked as Answered.

Comment: Thanks DhruvJoshi, This query works. Would it be possible to make this without sub query. I will mark this answer, but I wish to wait for an answer to see if possible to get without sub query.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear.

I understand from your question that you want to get a list of people who are reporting to your manager.

Lets get your manager's Id first.

Write a query to get ManagerID using your EmployeeID.

```
SELECT ManagerID
FROM tblEmployee
WHERE EmployeeID=@youremployeeID
```

Use this query as sub query and get a list of all the employees who are reporting to your manager.

```
SELECT EmployeeID
FROM tblEmployee
WHERE ManagerID=(SELECT ManagerID
                FROM tblEmployee
                WHERE EmployeeID=@youremployeeID)
```

**EDIT 1**

Why you  dont want to use a subquery?

Try something like this

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM tblEmployee E
 WHERE E.EmployeeId NOT IN (SELECT AssistantManagerEmployeeId 
                        FROM tblAssistantManager
                        WHERE A.ReportsToEmployeeId=@yourManagerID)
 AND E.ReportsToEmployeeId=@yourManagerID
```

Comment: I posted this answer before the question was edited. Keeping the answer as it is still relevant.

Comment: Thanks Kushal. Can you please check once the query, I need to get list of assistant managers under my manager and query the directs except the assistant manager. I am mostly looking without using subqueries if possible.